# Confusion in installing mod_jk on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, mod-jk

I am working from this document in trying to install mod_jk

http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_tomcat5_mod_jk_p2

I am at the step towards the bottom where they suggest to use the make command.  I was trying to use make like this and got an error:

```
/usr/src/jakarta-tomcat-connectors-1.2.15-src/jk/native$ sudo make mod_jk
make: *** No rule to make target `mod_jk'.  Stop.
```

What is the proper way to execute this command?  I am concerned that article may have outdated information.  Is this still the right way to do things?

Comment: Are you following instructions, or do you understand the process that is going on in order for the Makefile to work?  If it's the latter, you'll be able to solve your own problem.

Comment: @Tom I am trying to follow the instructions, and not sure what the exact process is to get all the needed components to work...kind of in mod_jk hell right now :)

Comment: What distro are you on?

Comment: @Tom I am on Ubuntu 10.04.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using Ubuntu 10.04, have you tried `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk`?

That should work, and then all you need to do is `sudo a2enmod jk` and `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

And it should work..

Comment: Wow that was pretty amazing.  I googled so much for the answer and you just got it boom!  Totally seemed to work since the installation messages ran by.  What is a good way to test that it actually worked by the way?

Comment: Check /etc/apache2/mods-available for something that looks like mod_jk.conf and mod_jk.load or possibly just jk.conf / jk.load

Comment: I have just this: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56 2009-11-06 15:10 jk.load - why would it say from 2009?  Thanks!

Comment: `ls` is showing you the file's mtime (the last time it was modified) which is probably when the package was built.  If you wanna see it's creation time (ctime), do `ls -lahc jk*` and it'll say something like `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56 2011-04-19 11:02 jk.load`